# search mongodb document based on subdocument value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using mongoosejs and have a MongoDB schema as follows for the user:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("my local id"),
"gravatar" : "user gravatar",
"username" : "users username",
"displayName" : "Shivaraman I",
"provider" : "facebook",
"providerData" : {
    "accessToken" : "facebook access token",
    "work" : [
        user work history
    ],
    "verified" : true,
    "updated_time" : "2015-02-04T13:23:44+0000",
    "timezone" : 1,
    "name" : "Shivaraman Iyer",
    "locale" : "en_GB",
    "link" : "user link",
    "last_name" : "Iyer",
    "gender" : "male",
    "first_name" : "Shivaraman",
    "email" : "email on facebook",
    "education" : [
        facebook user education list
    ],
    "id" : "user's facebook id"
},
...
"lastName" : "Iyer",
"firstName" : "Shivaraman",
}
```

I want to search the user based on his/her facebook `id` in the `providerData`. I did a lot of search and only found the `elemMatch` method which works for array sub documents. But I need something that works for this format of subdocument.

Have been searching a lot and haven't found anything. Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: collection.find({"providerData.id": id_to_find}) isn't it working???

Comment: it seems to be working in mongo shell but isn't working while using in mongoose
I am using : User.find({'providerData.id':user})  in mongoose which should work considering it means the same in mongoose

Comment: var query = collection.find();
query.where('providerData.id', id);

Comment: @gypsyCoder plz, add the answer and then KbLaD3 accept it to solve the question!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = collection.find(); 
query.where('providerData.id', id);
```

Then execute the query. It will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, you can use simple `find()` and you can directly pass the object location as key and its value as your projection.

In your case

```
db.collection.find({
  "providerData.id":id
});
```

This will give you result.

replace collection keyword with your collection name.